# Starting Solr on macOS

Tags: solr

How do I start Solr on MacOS? I just installed Solr with HomeBrew on macOS, but I am lost on how to get it started. I tried solr start, but it didn't work.

Thanks is much!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out to start Solr on macOS I had to run the following command:

```
solr start -p 8995
```